# AWS - How to limit calls to one endpoint in a domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api

We have an application hosted in AWS. We are now planning to have a public API for this application. It is expensive to service requests to this api. Is it possible to throttle requests to this api using AWS (not implementing logic in our application) such that if more than a certain number in a specified time are made they will be rejected?

Any advice is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: What level of throttling do you have in mind (in reqs/sec or reqs/min)?  What do you want to happen past the limit?  How often does the data returned by the API change?  Why will you be making an "expensive" API public?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: Level of throttling: (reqs/min) would be ideal. Perhaps HTTP 503 would be the response once limit has been exceeded. Data changes for every call; every call involves multiple calls to other rest APIs. Making this API public was required for it to be accessible to our clients (business requirement); and since we know our clients, we can suggest exponential backoff if the server response is anything besides 200.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to blacklist IPs that spam certain endpoints, you can use AWS WAF to create rate limiting rules for your API:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/protect-web-sites-services-using-rate-based-rules-for-aws-waf/

Answer (score 0):

I think there are at least two ways to do this:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-request-throttling.html

If you are using EC2 to host Linux instances, you could use `iptables` to rate limit by source IP address.